# "Error Occurred" on Document Set Approval Process

Tags: document-set

I am trying to use the Document Set approval process, it seems to be set up fine but when I run it it says "Error Occurred" - more details reveals "An error has occurred in Approve Document Set." ("Approve Document Set" is the name of the approval process).

Really can't work out what is causing this problem, require content approval is turned on so it's not that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approval workflow which should update the approval status of the document. Also, if you missed one step like setting the approval for the document library this simple task will fail at the end.

The workflow will start and run flawlessly until the end when it will try to update the approval status. If this setting is set to not to require content approval it will fail to update it hence throwing the above error.

So, if you encounter this, just go into the document library settings and go to Versioning Settings Page Set “Require content approval for submitted items ” to yes and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help but as I said in the original post content approval is already switched on.

Comment: I would suggest you to disable it & again enable it. I too faced same issue & was solved by disabling-enabling it. Hope it works!